# Access Sub-Regions in embedded Layouts

Tags: marionette

I have region which is attached to APP.

```
iApp.addRegions({
   sregion : "#sregion"
```

});

This region is attached to layout which is basically app layout which inturn have region

```
var iLayout = Marioneete.Layout.extend({
    template : LayoutTemplate,
    regions : {
        mainheader : "#mainheader",
        menu : "#mainmenu",
        content : "#mcontent" 
    }
```

Last region (content) is again layout

```
 template : MainContentLayout,
    regions : {
        contentmainheader : "#headmain",
        cotenttable : "#tablecontainer",
        cotentdetailer : "#issuedetailer" 
    }
});
```

I am storing this.applayout in controller through main page event so that I can access views for when other event happen as below.

```
               var MyApp = require('mapp');
               mlayout = new AppLayout();
               MyApp.sregion.show(mlayout);
               this.applayout = mlayout;
```

Within same controller upon selected item click I am trying to access the other "content detailer" as below which is not working.

```
                this.applayout.content.cotentdetailer.show(new SelectedIssue({id:options}));
```

How do we really access nested views from main region/layout? I don't see any method for this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create each layout and put them in the correct regions first:

```
//same as above, but I used correct parent layout
var MyApp = require('mapp');
this.ilayout = new iLayout();
MyApp.sregion.show(this.ilayout);

//You didnt include all your source code for this layout so I am guessing on the variable name.   
this.mLayout = new mLayout();
this.ilayout.content.show(this.mLayout)

//now you can access contentdetailer
this.mLayout.contentdetailer.show(new SelectedIssue({id:options}))
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was basically accessing the region of the layout which is in another region. Did some research and found that need to access the currenView and then region. I was thinking in that direction. Anyway it is solved like below.

```
this.applayout.content.currentView.cotentdetailer.show(new SelectedIssue({id:id}));
```